# Selenium in Python using Chrome, How to select element for clicking of Personal Info. options and then click on Personal Details

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

There is drop menu in a frame, in code it starts with `<div tag id=masterdiv, div class=submenu and onclick="SwitchMenu('sub1')">`,
I have to click first on `Personal Info`., and then select `Personal Details`
I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(href,'PersonalInfo/EmpPersonalInfo.jsp')
```

and

```
contains(@class,'submenu')]")
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("//a [@href=\"../EmployeeFiles/AcademicInfo/DailyStudentAttendanceEntry.jsp\"]")
```

None works.

```
<div id="masterdiv">
    <div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub1')">Personal Info.&nbsp <img src="../Images/arrow.gif"></div>
    <span class="submenu" id="sub1" style="display: none;">

        <img src="../Images/bullet4.gif">&nbsp;<a target="DetailSection" title="Personal Information" href="PersonalInfo/EmpPersonalInfo.jsp"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2">Personal Detail</font></a><br>

<img src="../Images/bullet4.gif">&nbsp;<a target="DetailSection" title="Personal Information" href="PersonalInfo/imprestAcc.jsp"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2">My Imprest Account</font></a><br>

        <img src="../Images/bullet4.gif">&nbsp;<a target="DetailSection" title="Self Attendance Detail" href="PersonalInfo\SelfAttendanceDetail.jsp"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2">Self Attendance</font></a><br>

        <img src="../Images/bullet4.gif">&nbsp;<a target="DetailSection" title="Change eMailID/Contact Numbers" href="PersonalInfo/EmpModifyEmailIDTelephone.jsp"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2">Edit Info.</font></a><br> }
```

Comment: What do you mean none works??? Is there any exception??? And which element is inside a frame??

Comment: I get  InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector:the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains[@href, 'PersonalInfo/EmpPersonalInfo.jsp']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"//span[@id='sub5']/descendant::a[containshref,'DailyStudentAttendanceEntry']"}

Comment: I want to select "Personal Info" from the compact menu frame

Comment: Dear Saurabh, I mean  I tried all three methods mentioned on top of the post but none of those works

Comment: Your provided locator looks like incorrect..try with provided answer and let me know..:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your provided locator looks incorrect that's why are  unable to find element, you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element present as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#first switch to frame if present 
driver.switch_to_frame("frame id or name")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# now find menu and click 
menu = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(., 'Personal Info')]")))
menu.click()

#now find submemu and click
submemu = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(., 'Personal Detail')]")))
submemu.click()
```

Comment: I got following error                                                                                   menu=WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(., 'Personal Info.')]")))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Ok to verify xpath at target page open browser console by pressing f12 and execute this `$x(".//*[contains(., 'Personal Info')]")` and let me know the result

Comment: And you need to provide delay time in long instead of `delay` param.. I have updated the answer now.. please try with updated answer and let me know

Comment: dear saurabh, same error appears, when I executed the command in console it returned empty list [ ]. But when I copy xpath it is `//*[@id="masterdiv"]/div[1]` when I use this is selenium it gives me NoSuchElementException.

Comment: This xpath `//*[@id="masterdiv"]/div[1]` returns empty list at browser console or this xpath `.//*[contains(., 'Personal Info')]`???

Comment: `.//*[conatins(.,'Personal Info')]` returns empty list i.e. `[]`,  but when I execute `//*[@id="masterdiv"]/div[1]` on console it selects the appropriate line but in program it returns `NoScuhElementException.`